# copying a user template in AD with C# DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using system.directoryservices.accountmanagement to manage my AD users.  I have several groups in my AD that have different types of users.  In each one of these groups I have a user that I use as a template.  Usually I go into AD and copy this user and create a user from there.  Is there a way to copy this user and create a new user from c#?  Or a similar way of accomplishing this?  I don't mind running it in powershell.

Thanks,